# printer sharing stop working after I transfer from cable ethernet to wifi wireless

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, printing

I am using ubuntu server 16.04 as my printer server, use windows to connect to server, and send print jobs. they are working no problem till..

I was managed to change cable ethernet of this server to wifi, which is more convenience for avoiding wires everywhere.

I am using the same static ip for wifi connections, samba in this server is working perfectly without any change, but the printer sharing is not working.

print on server is fine, 
connect to CUPS web interface is fine, it can also can print a test page in there,

but I just can't send files from my Windows to server for printing. there isn't any queue in server print list. :(

please help.

Comment: @user68186 I did reinstall the printer after I change server to wifi, printer installed without any problem, also can check the properties of printer, but can't print test page. :(

Comment: In your printer properties in Windows, try changing the driver to `Microsoft IPP` as the driver.

Comment: @Terrance yes, I uninstall and reinstall printer with Microsoft IPP driver, which is works. please write a answer for your suggestion, I will accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, go to your Printer Properties by right-clicking your printer, then go to the Advanced Tab.  In there you should see the driver.  Click on Change driver and choose the `Microsoft IPP` driver.  Apply the changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it does helps, especially for the windows 10 connect to the old shared printer.

Comment: @user3127293 Glad it helps!  I had to do it for an old Samsung ML-1430 on CUPS and Windows 10 for proper printing as well.  Especially since Windows 10 does not have the ML-1430 driver.